# How do I download my iOS App's original files?

Tags: ios, xcode, download, app-store-connect

My App was recently removed from the App Store by Apple because it didn't comply with their new terms and agreements.

I have since monkeyed around with the original binary so much that I can't even get the thing to run.

Does anyone know how to download files from an iOS App that you've already had available on the App Store?

Thanks,

Tyler

Comment: Certainly you used Time Machine or some other backup and certainly you used source code control and possibly you zipped up your project and stored the zip file on some thumb drive or in some cloud account. Just restore your app from one of those many backups you made.

Comment: And you do realize that the ipa you submit to Apple has none of your app's source code, right? You can probably extract resource files and the Info.plist, but that's it. No code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have since monkeyed around with the original binary so much that I can't even get the thing to run.

I'm not sure what you mean here, there's not much you can really do to a binary. But you can always build a new binary from the source code. Or, if you mean that you've monkeyed around with the source code so much that your app no longer builds or runs, then you'll probably want to go back to a previous commit in your revision control system. You do use a revision control system like `git` (and hopefully Github), right? If not, then the next best option is to use your Time Machine backup to go back a few days or weeks to the point when your code was last in good shape.

> Does anyone know how to download files from an iOS App that you've already had available on the App Store?

It's a one-way street, I'm afraid: you submit your app, and then Apple does whatever they do to it to make it available in the App Store. That probably means signing the app, and also slicing it up so that any particular download only has the components needed for the device to which the download occurs. Anyway, the App Store submission process isn't like storing something on a virtual hard drive in the cloud -- you can't just upload and files and then expect to be able to download them again.